# Storing Business Logic in Tables rather than Stored Procedure or Application

Tags: database, business-logic, logic

The requirement is that once the product has been delivered, user can update the logic as he wants.

An example of logic I have is follows-

An institute teaches English has following requirements -

1. At the time of registration student can choose either **Writing** or **Reading** or both.
2. Student can choose **Speaking** only if it is being offered in the same Term as well as it is starting within 2 weeks.

Applying this logic in the application or stored procedure is fairly simple. But as per requirements, above scenario could change.

How can we achieve something like above.

Comment: I think you have to define the level of configurability the end user wants and design for that and no more. Otherwise you end up giving them an entire programming language and a manual on how to use it, and that way madness lies

Comment: You need a better understanding about how capable these users are. If they know how to alter a stored procedure, the solution is easy.

Comment: I am not clear on your scenario. There is no way the client is going to access the data without at least a query of some kind. Has the client really requested no application? Or can the requirements be fulfilled through allowing the user to configure the logic of the application?  Why do the logic parameters need to be stored in tables? Why not an external configuration file? Can you clarify the scenario? Are you really limited to Tables? Are Views allowed?

Comment: Ofcourse there is application. Main thing is once the product is delivered, and if there is any need of changing the business logic then they want to be able to that themselves

Comment: Your logic rules should be worded generically (the conditions). This will guide you the structure that your backing tables need to be. The actual logic should be implemented as stored procedures or in the application.

Answer (score 2):

> Main thing is once the product is delivered, and if there is any need
>   of changing the business logic then they want to be able to that
>   themselves

That's potentially a *huge* issue. You need to be able to scope this, and determine what they're likely to want to change e.g.

1. switch between a couple of behaviours? Then provide a config/flag to provide that switching. You can trivially test that and deploy it with little issue
2. use an API that you've provided, and they can write plugins that (say) listen to well-publicised events/calls, react to those etc. You can then document that, test against those interfaces and give your users a well-maintained API that they can write against. You can control data visibility etc. and manage this
3. Allow them to plug into your solution and write anything against your application. At this stage you may as well give them the source code and relinquish control over this. You don't want to be supporting an application against which your customers can do/change almost anything

The more control you yield, the more potential you have for support issues and difficulties in managing this.

To address your specific issue, storing business logic in tables would be a nightmare to manage (for your clients and for you). How are you going to validate and structure this? Tables can only allow the means to provide simple configuration s(e.g. setting flags, numeric limits etc. - unless you store some scripts in there - which is another issue entirely)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a table that stores courses that can be taken with each other: CourseCombination (id, course1id, course2id). Then you could create a table that stores a single value representing the time frame a student can take any given combination of courses: CourseCombinationTimeFrame.

Then in your application create a place for the system administrators to combine courses and set the time frame a student can take any given combination of courses. In this case they would group Writing and Reading, and the time frame would be 2 weeks. This stores Writing and Reading in the CourseCombination table, and updates the CourseCombinationTimeFrame value to 2.

Now, in your application, create a block of logic that validates course selections for students:

1. Query the combination table.
2. As the student chooses a course, check the selected course does not violate combinations.
3. Take the min start date of the courses the student has selected.
4. Take the max start date of the courses the student has selected.
5. Query the time frame table.
6. Check that max - min is within the time frame.

This is just one example. *But please note, they cannot change the business logic itself, only the parameters of the logic.*

If they really want control over the logic itself, then they are basically asking for the source code, and I am assuming they have an IT guy who wants to be able to customize the software post production. If that is the case, then make sure your contract is very clear about what you are delivering and for what payment. Ideally, if they want to change the logic itself, they would contact you for more work. You should try to sell them on this idea because you will be best equipped to make changes and it will be cheaper for them in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is pretty common in workflow applications. Business logic may not be in database tables but it can often be dynamically loaded by the system and designed by domain experts.
Workflow foundation may be worth a look.

Comment: That's something new. Sure I shall take a look at WWF.

Comment: I think ppl call it WF because of these guys http://www.worldwildlife.org/

Comment: Can I integrate .NET application with WF?

Comment: Yes. It is a framework you can develop with. There are many examples.